helm install raycluster kuberay/ray-cluster --version 1.1.1 stuck at pulling image
I follow the documentation to deploy a raycluster on kubernete, I already setup a Kubernete cluster, now I am deploy a Ray cluster on top of it. https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/cluster/kubernetes/getting-started/raycluster-quick-start.html 
After I run helm install raycluster kuberay/ray-cluster --version 1.1.1,
the two pod are not ready
sidc@ubuntu-m00:~$ kubectl get pods --selector=ray.io/cluster=raycluster-kuberay --watch
NAME                                          READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
raycluster-kuberay-head-26qbh                 0/1     ContainerCreating   0          9m37s
raycluster-kuberay-worker-workergroup-2czt2   0/1     Init:0/1            0          9m37s
Events:
Type    Reason     Age    From               Message

Normal  Scheduled  5m35s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/raycluster-kuberay-head-26qbh to pi-w01
Normal  Pulling    5m34s  kubelet            Pulling image "rayproject/ray:2.9.0"
I check the head and worker, the data indicate they are still pulling the image, I know the network is slow, but not really sure if it's due to the slow network or stuck
